# How do i fix npm build error in windows 10?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I tried everything but not able to install even a single npm module.

How should I fix this?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.590]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\npmtestfolder>npm install bootstrap
```

> ed25519@0.0.4 install C:\Users\Dell\node_modules\ed25519
>   node-gyp rebuild

```
C:\Users\Dell\node_modules\ed25519>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Users\Dell\node_modules\ed25519\build\ed25519.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.D
efault.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on
disk.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Dell\node_modules\ed25519
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Dell\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Dell\package.json'
npm WARN bootstrap@4.3.1 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.3.1 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.14.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN Dell No description
npm WARN Dell No repository field.
npm WARN Dell No README data
npm WARN Dell No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ed25519@0.0.4 (node_modules\ed25519):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ed25519@0.0.4 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

+ bootstrap@4.3.1
updated 1 package and audited 5449 packages in 13.153s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for your above mentioned error. Like your system don't get the proper path to `buildsystem`.

Your project's name also matters.

Your CMD's rights matters too like [`Run as an Administrator`].

Have you initialised your project with `npm init`? There is also written that `package.json` is not found. You are installing `npm` library on your windows root User's directory(here `Dell` is yours). Don't do that.

Make a separate directory and `cd` your `dir` by CMD with `Administrator`. Initialise your directory with `npm init`. Then try to install your respective libraries with (i.e `npm i bootstrap`).

This may help you. And if not, this are the best practices. You should follow, when you working on Node.

Comment: @AbhishekNilekar Welcome :) You can correct the answer. So that it will helpful to others too.